# XML deserialize derived class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

The problem is XmlType("Erand") name is same as my class Erand, if I changed the class name to like Eranda it worked, is there any other way to say .net what to do?

I have an class

```
        public class Erand
        {
            public long ID { get; set; }
            public string AsjaNumber { get; set; }
         }
```

and

```
[XmlType("Erand")]
    public class ErandTsiv : Erand
    {
        [XmlElement("ID_KIS")]
        public long idKis { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ID_ET")]
        public long idEt { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to deserialize ErandTsiv

from xml like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfErand xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Erand>
   <ID>573838383</ID>
   <ID_KIS>573838383</ID_KIS>
   <ID_ET></ID_ET>
   <AsjaNumber>2-08-88785</AsjaNumber>
</Erand>
</ArrayOfErand>
```

like

```
var stream = new StringReader(erandid);
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(new List<ErandTsiv>().GetType());
                var erandTsivs = (IList<ErandTsiv>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);`
```

but get an error

```
{"There was an error reflecting type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Aet.test.unit.application.utility.TsivTapsustaTest.ErandTsiv]'."}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deserialize this exact XML you should rely on a custom List definition for your `List<ErandTsiv>`, leaving out the `XmlType` on `ErandTsiv`

Your class definitions would then be :

```
public class Erand
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string AsjaNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ErandTsiv : Erand
{
    [XmlElement("ID_KIS")]
    public long idKis { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ID_ET")]
    public long idEt { get; set; }

}

[XmlRoot("ArrayOfErand")]
public class ErandTsivList 
{
    public ErandTsivList()
    {
        Erands = new List<ErandTsiv>();
    }
    [XmlElement("Erand")]
    public List<ErandTsiv> Erands { get; set; }
}
```

And the deserialization would be :

```
    var stream = new StringReader(x);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ErandTsivList));
    var erandTsivs = (ErandTsivList)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    // your List<ErandTsiv> would then be in erandTsivs.Erands
```